# How to close the browser each time after executing a scenario and launching the url again on running the next scenario?

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am using protractor-cucumber -typescript framework where in my requirement is to run 2 scenarios from a feature file. After executing one scenario, it should close the browser and then again launch the URL in the browser and run the second scenario. I understand that I have to update accordingly in my hooks file, but unable to identify it.

I have tried calling the browser.get("URL"); in the beforeEach scenario and closing the browser (ie) browser.quit(); in afterEach but that didn't work(VError: after each hook errored).

**hooks.ts:**

```
const { BeforeAll, After, Before, Status } = require("cucumber");
import * as fs from "fs";
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { config } from "../config/config";
import { async } from "q";
import { AfterAll } from "cucumber";

BeforeAll({ timeout: 1000 * 1000 }, async () => {
    await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
});

After(async function (scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
        const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");
    }
    else {
        var attach = this.attach;
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
            var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, "base64");
            return attach(decodedImage, "image/png");
        })
    }
});

AfterAll({ timeout: 1000 * 1000 }, async () => {
    await browser.quit();
});
```

**config.ts:**

```
import * as path from "path";
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
import { Reporter } from "../support/reporter";
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
export const config: Config = {

    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    baseUrl: "url",
    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
    },
    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    specs: [
        "../../features/*.feature",
    ],

    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
        Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
    },

    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
        require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js",
            "../../typeScript/support/*.js"],
        strict: true,

        tags: "(@Scenario1 or @Scenario2 )",
    },
    onComplete: () => {
        Reporter.createHTMLReport();
    },
};
```

Expected is to close the browser after each scenario and launch the URL and run the next scenario as each of the scenarios are a different page altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in your config

```
restartBrowserBetweenTests: true
```

This restarts your browser for every `it` block.

Hope it helps you

Comment: I am using protractor cucumber framework and not jasmine.Is everything fine with the hooks.ts file.As I tried, the command you suggested but its not closing the browser and running the new scenario in another browser.Two scenarios I tried to run were failure

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pain. Basically Javascript is not the best language for Automated tests, due to hard possibility to override provided APIs / test runners (which is easy for Python/Java). 
In case you'll add `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true` in your protractor.conf this will restart browser after each scenario. BUT! `After` hook you are using will be executed after - so you will have blank page as screenshots (as browser just started). 
you need to update After hook to a following (as you taking screenshot independing on result - I've edited that a bit (use default value of `restartBrowserBetweenTests` by not specifying it. Or set it directly to `restartBrowserBetweenTests:false`):

```
After(async function (scenario) {
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
      var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, "base64");
      scenario.attach(decodedImage, "image/png");
    });
return browser.restart();
});
```